# Spring Data Rest ResourceProcessor for Projection Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have created the following `Projection`

```
@Projection(name = "select", types = {Organisation.class})
public interface OrganisationSelectProjection {

    Long getId();

    String getName();

}
```

Which I want to basically use in a "Select" component so I need the least data possible. So I also wanted to remove all the links with a `ResourceProcessor`, so I created this:

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<OrganisationSelectProjection>> organisationProcessor() {
    return resource -> {
        resource.removeLinks();
        return resource;
    };
}
```

However, it looks like this breaks the entire API since whatever endpoint I hit I get the following exception message `org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources cannot be cast to org.springframework.hateoas.Resource`

Any idea what I have doen wrong?

Comment: What version of *spring-hateoas* do you use? Spring-boot 1.5.2 (current) has spring-hateoas-0.23 where it must work fine...

Comment: I'm using 0.20.0 with Spring-Boot 1.4.3, but I will update to 1.5.2 and try it out

Comment: Tested with 1.5.2 and still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try [this](https://github.com/Cepr0/restvotes/blob/master/src/main/java/restvotes/rest/processor/AnyResourceProcessors.java) instead of your bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to keep anonymous class in place, using `ResourceSupport` instead of `Resource` can resolve the issue.

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<ResourceSupport> organisationProcessor() {
    return resource -> {
        resource.removeLinks();
        return resource;
    };
}
```

But in this case the processor will be used on each and every resource regardless of type of the content (you can check that inside the method body though).

Instead of anonymous descendant of `ResourceProcessor` you can define it as a stand-alone class:

```
public class OrganizationResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<OrganisationSelectProjection>> {
    @Override
    public Resource<OrganisationSelectProjection> process(Resource<OrganisationSelectProjection> resource) {
        resource.removeLinks();
        return resource;
    }
}

@Bean
public OrganizationResourceProcessor  organisationProcessor() {
    return new OrganizationResourceProcessor();
}
```

The issue you expereinced has something to do with type erasure since there is no any type parameters in the anonymous class implementation. Your definition is type-safe but it lacks that type-related data which is used at runtime when determining whether particular `ResourceProcessor` can process a resource. So `spring-data-rest` thinks that anonymous `organizationProcessor` can process `PagedResources` and feeds it to the processor where `ClassCastException` happens.

Not everything `spring-data-rest` puts through `ResourceProcessor`s is a `Resource`. There can be different descendants of `org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport` class (like `PagedResources` in your case) and majority of them are not inherited from `Resource`.

Comment: Unfortunately that a limitation of the way lambdas are implemented. I've brought this issue up on the mailing list but didn't get too much response: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2017-January/010675.html